# Convert Varchar to Numeric

Tags: sql, sql-server, decimal, numeric, varchar

I need to convert imported `VarChar` to Text, and have found this code

```
select * from [VWSA_Sewells].[dbo].[Sewells_1Mth_Composite] where ISNUMERIC(201307)=0
alter table [VWSA_Sewells].[dbo].[Sewells_1Mth_Composite] Add 201307_Temp decimal(17,4) 
GO

--Update temporary column with the values from 201307
update [VWSA_Sewells].[dbo].[Sewells_1Mth_Composite] set 201307_Temp = 201307
GO

--set 201307 to null
update [VWSA_Sewells].[dbo].[Sewells_1Mth_Composite] set 201307 = NULL
GO

--Change the datatype of 201307
alter table [VWSA_Sewells].[dbo].[Sewells_1Mth_Composite]  alter column 201307         decimal(17,4) 
GO

--Update the numeric values in 201307
--before doing this you have make sure select * from [VWSA_Sewells].[dbo].    [Sewells_1Mth_Composite] where ISNUMERIC(201307_Temp)=0 returns nothing.
update [VWSA_Sewells].[dbo].[Sewells_1Mth_Composite] set 201307 = Cast(201307_Temp as     decimal(17,4))
GO
```

My table contains a `Ratio_ID` in column 1 eg `VW1537_is02p` and the actual `Ratio` in column 2 under the heading 201307.

Column 201307 contains ONLY numerical data eg 0.2242, 5042050.40 etc. None of the numbers have more than 4 decimals.

My error msg in SQL Server 2008 is

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
>   Incorrect syntax near '201307'.

As long as decimal provides for amounts up to 1 billion and 4 digits and allows for queries (>1 etc), we can stick to decimal.

Any ideas?

Comment: If your table and column names start with number you have to use square brackets around them. That's your error. `alter table... Add [201307_Temp] decimal..`

Comment: Problem now is, that the values in the table were replaced by the column heading?

Comment: That have likely happened because you missed to put brackets somewhere. Probably on `set [201307_Temp] = [201307]`

Comment: I did forget that one, will test quickly! Same issue - ends up with just NULL's

Comment: Can you provide some sample data? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9a89b/1

Comment: Where can I leave the sample data for you? Which tab/link in SQLFiddle?

Comment: On the left side, modify `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT INTO` statements according to your model and data.

Comment: Right, you can have a look - it's got issues with data truncation

Comment: You have to give me the link :) Or even better edit your question to include it.

Comment: I used your SQLFIddle link? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9a89b/1

Comment: Link changes every time something is edited. So my link still shows what I wrote last.

Comment: Right, try this one! http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5e39a

Comment: This seems to work fine? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5e39a/2

Comment: THanks a lot - a smaller sample of data DOES work, so back to the data verification drawing board for me!!!!

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
select * from [VWSA_Sewells].[dbo].[Sewells_1Mth_Composite] where ISNUMERIC([201307])=0
alter table [VWSA_Sewells].[dbo].[Sewells_1Mth_Composite] Add [201307_Temp] decimal(17,4) 
GO
--Update temporary column with the values from 201307
update [VWSA_Sewells].[dbo].[Sewells_1Mth_Composite] set [201307_Temp] = [201307]
GO
--set 201307 to null
update [VWSA_Sewells].[dbo].[Sewells_1Mth_Composite] set [201307] = NULL
GO
--Change the datatype of 201307
alter table [VWSA_Sewells].[dbo].[Sewells_1Mth_Composite]  alter column [201307] decimal(17,4) 
GO
--Update the numeric values in 201307
--before doing this you have make sure select * from [VWSA_Sewells].[dbo].    [Sewells_1Mth_Composite] where ISNUMERIC(201307_Temp)=0 returns nothing.
update [VWSA_Sewells].[dbo].[Sewells_1Mth_Composite] set [201307] = Cast([201307_Temp] as decimal(17,4))
GO
```

Raj

Comment: HI Raj, I end up with NULL's?